# How to remove dict keys if value is empty

Tags: python

In my form post request I'm grabbing all form info, but it seems as though there are some empty keys and values. I'd like to remove all instances of empty keys and values. This what I have so far, and it's obviously not working.

```
post_dict = dict(request.POST)
item_data = {}

for key, value in post_dict.items():
    if value is None:
        del post_dict[key]
    field = key.split('[')[1].replace(']', '')
    item_data[field] = ''.join(value)

print(item_data)
```

What the print item_data looks like:

```
{'': '', 'username': 'johndoe', 'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com', ...
```

If you delete the key, will it delete its respective value? How can I get rid of empty keys and values?

Comment: Do you mean to do `if value == ''`?

Comment: `if value is None` will only match the precise object `None`. If you just want to remove [false-y](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) values (`None`, `''`, `0`, `[]`, ...) use `if not value:`.

Comment: You should probably continue to the next iteration of the loop after deleting.

Comment: @JETM no, i tried that aswell.. still shows the empty key and value

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean?

Comment: Even when the value is None, you still do `item_data[field] = ''.join(value)`. Don't you want to skip that for the elements you're deleting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm `if not value:` didn;t work. still shows the empty key and value

Comment: Why would you ever have a key with no value? The form should always a key associated with a field in a form. Otherwise, the you have bigger problem on the form building side.

Comment: @Barmar yes but an else doesn't do the trick

Comment: @Merlin agreed. yes for some reason theres empty keys and values. But I'm dealing with the hand i'm dealt. :\

Comment: @Merlin If you leave a field empty in a form it will be an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar Not the key, only the value

Comment: @Merlin Right. I think that empty key is coming from `field = key.split('[')[1].replace(']', '')` because the key doesn't have `[` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
post_dict = {'': '', 'item_data[username]': ['johndoe'], 'item_data[email]': ['johndoe@gmail.com'], 'item_data[campus]': ['madison']}
item_data = {}

for key, value in post_dict.items():
    strlist = key.split('[')
    if len(strlist) == 1:
        continue

    new_key = strlist[1].replace(']', '')
    new_value = ''.join(value)

    # add to the dict if both new_key and new_value are non-empty
    if all([new_key, new_value]):
        item_data[new_key] = new_value

print(item_data)
# Output
{'username': 'johndoe', 'campus': 'madison', 'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com'}
```

---

Previous answer: Delete those items from a dict whose key or value is empty.

```
d = {'': '', 'username': 'johndoe', 'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com'}

for k, v in d.items():
    if not any([k, v]):
        del d[k]

print(d)
{'username': 'johndoe', 'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com'}
```

Comment: That top portion throws: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Modelesq, what is the content of `post_dict`?

Comment: `{'item_data[username]': ['johndoe'], 'item_data[email]': ['johndoe@gmail.com'], 'item_data[campus]': ['madison'],...` and so on

Comment: @Modelesq, your data might contain `'':''`. I edited my answer. Pls check it again.

Comment: YES! You're awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
new_item_data={k:item_data[k] for k in item_data if item_data[k]}
```

Any keys that do not have values will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key, value in post_dict.items():
```

In your code you are iterating on `post_dict`.
However, in the line `del post_dict[key]` you are modifying the iterator, so it will provide an inconsistent view of the dictionary to `for`. It is not good to add or delete keys to the dictionary that you are iterating on.

This may give the result you wanted

```
post_dict = dict(request.POST)
item_data = {}

for key, value in post_dict.items():
    if value == "":
        continue
    if key == "":
        continue
    field = key.split('[')[1].replace(']', '')
    item_data[field] = ''.join(value)

print(item_data)
```

Comment: I'm sure the items() call will return a copy of the list of items, meaning deleting from the original dict does not actually effect the iteration... Except you are correct! I just wrote a simple test and it definitely modifies the dict you are iterating through +1

Comment: Any reason why it would throw `IndexError: list index out of range` :\ ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do what you want using one of these:

```
dict_1 = {'': '', 'username': 'johndoe', 'email':'', }

dict_2 = dict(x for x in dict_1.iteritems() if any(x))
print dict_2  # {'username': 'johndoe', 'email': ''}

dict_3 = dict(x for x in dict_1.iteritems() if all(x))
print dict_3  # {'username': 'johndoe'}
```